# combining functionality of two Node servers with different initial set up

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have two node servers and I need to combine them so one server has the functionality of both. They were set up a little differently and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

The first server has the require statements at the top, routes in the middle and creates the server at the bottom like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
etc..

// middleware

// routes

http.createServer(app, function(req, res){
// get files
// check for errors

}).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The second one looks like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = app.listen(80)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , fs = require('fs')

var arr= [];

app.get('/aRoute', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  var data = {
    // parse query string
  };
  arr.push(data);

  io.sockets.emit('update', data);
  res.end("OK");
});

app.get('/someOutput', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(footData));
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
});
```

I cut pasted part of it so now the first server script looks (roughly) like this.

```
// All imports
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');
var connect = require('connect');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var io = require('socket.io');

// middleware

// routes

// trying to make this a route
var arr= [];

app.get('/aRoute', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  var data = {
    // parse query string
  };
  arr.push(data);

  io.sockets.emit('update', data);
  res.end("OK");
});

app.get('/someOutput', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(footData));
});

// THIS GIVES ME ERRORS RIGHT HERE
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
});

http.createServer(app, function(req, res){
// get files
// check for errors

}).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Combining the two scripts has resulted in an error listed below at the line listed below.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined:

// THIS GIVES ME ERRORS RIGHT HERE
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
});
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error after changing the two require statements and moving the server creation and listening to the bottom of the server. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: There is no a general way to "combine" several scripts. You must completely understand how every of them work and then carefully merge logic. And again - there are no generic advices, it's a unique per script action.

Comment: Why combine them?, in the case both have their respective domain you can use something like apache or nginx to route them from the outside and run both apps on different ports.

Comment: @zerkms yes, i understand. I have edited the post to include more details about where I am now and what errors I am getting.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I was thinking to make this another page on my current website. I would need another domain name and IP address to route between them or I can run two Node servers on my machine and run them on different ports?

Answer (score 0):

You're requiring socket.io, which has a `.listen` method, not an `.on` method. Once you call `.listen`, you'll get back an object that has the `.on` method you're trying to use.

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

(You're also missing `server`, which is created in the second script by calling `express().listen(somePortNumberLike80)`

You can't just copy and paste code and expect it to work, really.

Comment: I didn't really expect it to work, but I do want to know why it doesn't work. Can I have io = require('socket.io').listen(server) as well as the http.createServer()... in the same script so I have two listeners? Or can I include all the file serving functionality into the io = require... statement? I'm trying to look this up myself, but I'm new and don't understand a lot of what I'm reading in the documentation.